# Validation in angular for datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnNd8.jpg)I used a datepicker. On datepicker i am adding validation of required and date is invalid. But i need to show it one at a time. When datepicker field is empty it should show me field is required and when date is invalid then it should show date is invalid error. But now it is coming together. How to solve it.

I am attaching the image please have a look[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC7JF.jpg)

Comment: It’s better to post the actual relevant code instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

```
        **HTML**
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
      <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
      </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

TS:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker with custom icon */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-custom-icon-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-custom-icon-example.html',
})
export class DatepickerCustomIconExample {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).